# Python function from imported file shows as undefined

Tags: python, function, python-import, importerror

I have a moveslist.py file with function `movesSelection` and a main.py file. Within my main.py, I've made sure that my variables are set to global and I had another function `makeNewChar`. Within `makeNewChar`, I'm trying to call `movesSelection` but I get "NameError: name 'movesSelection' is not defined.

Since my moveslist.py uses some global variables from main, I imported main into the file.
For my main.py, I did `from moveslist import *`. I also tried `import movesList` and `from moveslist import movesSelection`. All of those threw back errors.

How can I use `movesSelection` within my main.py?

Answer (score 1):

There may be a few different reasons but some of the most common are having a file with the same name or likely the file you are looking for is in another directory so i will show you my correct here

[Edit] You should remove the .py when importing example below

```
## This is "main.py" keep that in mind when viewing
## Change line 4 to import and the python file as Func = Func.py in this context
import Func
Func.Activate()
```

```
## This is "Func.py"
class Activate:(
    print("Hello World!")
)
```

**Or you may need to do as says below!**

```
##Include file extension and move the file with the folder in the correct space and i'd appreciate it if you'd be so kind to mark this question as correct 
import movesSelection.py
```

Comment: Hey! Thanks for the quick response!
I made sure the two files were in the same folder and no other file has the same name. `movesSelection` is the function in "moveslist.py" that I'm trying to use in "main.py".

Comment: Oh no, shadowskillz you use the name of the file not the function eg. import library_name and now you would say on the next line library_name.function_name()

Comment: also if the answer is correct or helps you please mark it as correct!

Comment: So in my main.py, I have 
`import moveslist` (which is my other file name) 
and then I did `moveslist.movesSelection (to call the function inside the moveslist file) 

It didn't work... :(

Answer (score 0):

Add "from moveslist import movesSelection" into makeNewChar.
You do not have to add the .py suffix when you import.

Comment: I ended up with this error and I'm not sure what it means `ImportError: cannot import name 'movesSelection' from partially initialized module 'moveslist'`